# Tails: Separation of different identities within the same session

Tags: tails

On the Tails webpage, the users are warned that different identities are not separated "magically" within the same Tails session. It is recommended to shutdown and reboot Tails before using a different identity.

Does this also apply to the TorBrowser shipped with Tails?

In the latest version of Tails, the TorBrowser contains the "New Identity" feature of Torbutton. By clicking "New Identity" on the green onion in the tool bar of TorBrowser, a new TorBrowser session is generated. As far as I understand, the TorBrowser in Tails behaves the same way as the stand-alone TorBrowser does with regard to session separation.

Do I really need to shutdown and reboot Tails to separate different browsing sessions and thus, identities?
Or is it sufficient to use the "New Identity" feature of Torbutton to separate different browsing sessions/identities?

(Remember: I do NOT mean the "New Identity" feature of Vidalia!)

Answer (score 2):

The warning in Tails documentation predates a “New identity” option in the Tor Browser that would clear cookies, browsing history and the likes. If the only application used in Tails in the web browser, then it's likely safe to rely on that feature to create a new, unlinkable, browsing session.

If any other network facing application is used, it's probably better to reboot.